# Macro Excel: InputBox to key in rows and column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a coding which helps me to select the range I want. But what I need now is to key in a specific number of rows and column into the input box then the range will get selected. For example, I need 5 rows and 4 columns. I want to be able to key in 5 x 4 into the input box.

My code:

```
Sub InsertShape()

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim Shp4 As Shape

  Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Please Select Range", Type:=8)
  With Rng
  Set Shp4 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(1, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
  If Rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
  Else
    Rng.Select
    Shp4.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
  End If

  With Shp4.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
  End With

  Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
  Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous

  End With  
  End Sub
```

Comment: I'd knock together a custom `UserForm` for this. You *could* use the `VBA.InputBox`, but by the time you get done with all the validation and parsing, it would probably be more work.

Comment: I need to use a `UserForm` for this? How do I do it? Do u have any example to show me?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Sub InsertShape2()

    Dim my_row As Integer
    Dim my_col As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range

    my_row = InputBox("How many rows?", Default:=0)
    my_col = InputBox("How many columns?", Default:=0)
    If my_row = 0 Or my_col = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
    Else
        Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(my_row - 1, my_col - 1))
        Rng.Select
        ' and do the rest of your shape stuff here
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't be Default:=1 and my_row = 0 **OR** my_col = 0 ?

Comment: Correct @Jeeped.  I've changed it to `my_row = 0` **OR** `my_col = 0`.  I still think `Default := 0` so the user can just hit enter twice to get out of the dialog and nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you say:

> For example, I need 5 rows and 4 columns. I want to be able to key in 5 x 4 into the input box.

If you want the user to be able to enter a string like `5x4` then you need to set the [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx) of the `InputBox` to 2. You can then Split on the `x` and use the current user selected cell and `Resize` it by the number either side of the `x`. Example below in `InsertShapeRxC`.

If you want to use `Type` of 8 in the `InputBox` then user will need to enter a real range like G10:J15 or something. You can then insert the shape and format it etc. But if you have `Type` of 8 and they enter `5x4` it will error. Example below in `InsertShapeWithRange`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertShapeRxC()

    Dim strInput As String
    Dim lngRows As Long, lngColumns As Long
    Dim rngShape As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

    ' get user input as string
    strInput = Application.InputBox("Please enter RxC", Type:=2)

    ' get rows and columns from input - expected RxC
    lngRows = Split(strInput, "x", -1, vbTextCompare)(0)
    lngColumns = Split(strInput, "x", -1, vbTextCompare)(1)

    ' resize current selection to rows and columns as input
    Set rngShape = Selection
    Set rngShape = rngShape.Resize(lngRows, lngColumns)

    ' get reference to worksheet
    Set ws = rngShape.Parent

    ' add shape
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(1, rngShape.Left, rngShape.Top, rngShape.Width, rngShape.Height)
    With shp
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        With .Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End With

    With rngShape
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End Sub

Sub InsertShapeWithRange()

    Dim strInput As String
    Dim lngRows As Long, lngColumns As Long
    Dim rngShape As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

    ' get user input as string
    Set rngShape = Application.InputBox("Please enter range", Type:=8)

    ' get reference to worksheet
    Set ws = rngShape.Parent

    ' add shape
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(1, rngShape.Left, rngShape.Top, rngShape.Width, rngShape.Height)
    With shp
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        With .Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End With

    With rngShape
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Note to others: Excel's application.inputbox accepts a type:= parameter. VBA's regular inputbox does not.

Comment: This works perfectly, just what I need. Thanks @Robin !

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do the job they way you had it in mind.

```
Sub SelectRange()
    ' 22 Mar 2017

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Specs As String
    Dim Splt() As String
    Dim R As Long, C As Long
    Dim Done As Boolean

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)                   ' = A1
    Do While Not Done
        Specs = InputBox("Enter R x C")
        If Len(Specs) Then
            If InStr(1, Specs, "x", vbTextCompare) Then
                Do While InStr(1, Specs, "xx", vbTextCompare)
                    Specs = Replace(Specs, "xx", "x", Compare:=vbTextCompare)
                Loop
                Splt = Split(Specs, "x")
                R = CLng(Val(Splt(0)))
                C = CLng(Val(Splt(1)))
                If R < 1 Or C < 1 Then
                    MsgBox "Row and column numbers can't" & vbCr & _
                           "be smaller than 1.", vbCritical, _
                           "Invalid row or column number"
                Else
                    Rng.Resize(R, C).Select
                    Done = True
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Invalid entry without ""x""", vbInformation
            End If
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```